# Change Paid Android App to Subscription Model but keep it free for past users

Tags: android, google-play, android-billing

My client wants to turn a paid Android app into a free one with subscription options for premium features.

However users that have paid for in the past should not need to subscribe for premium features.

How can I technically check if a users has bought the app once it is free? Does the Google License Verification Library still provide a license even the app has been turned into a free one?

I learned that it's possible to see the purchase history for in-app/subscription billings but for a onetime paid app, the billing library does not track it.

Any help is appreciated :)

I checked the Google billing library and searched for examples but it does not provide any good answer.

Comment: I don't know if this is the only way but I experienced such a change from user perspective: an app had free base app + paid premium unlocker app and changed to one app with subscription model. When changing they made a special offer only to existing users who had paid for the one-time paid unlocker app: a special time-limited subscription was offered for 0.09€ (the lowest possible price). This subscription is not time limited and unlocks the app to the old paid state.